# Generate random numbers that are in sorted into order without duplicates Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I am creating a lottery number generator and am having trouble randomly generating 6 numbers without duplicates. Here is the code so far for generating 6 numbers and adding them to the randomNumbers array and sorting them:

```
var randomNumbers = [];  
var number; 

function addNumsToArray() {  
    for(var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {  
        number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 59 + 1);  
        randomNumbers.push(number);  
    }  
}  

function sortArray() {  
    randomNumbers.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});  
    console.log(randomNumbers);  
}  

addNumsToArray();  
sortArray();
```

Comment: if array already contains current number - do not push it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var randomNumbers = [];  

function addNumsToArray() {  
    for(var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {  
        number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 59 + 1);
        randomNumbers.push(generateUniqNumber());  
    }  
}  

function sortArray() {  
    randomNumbers.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});  
    console.log(randomNumbers);  
}  

function generateUniqNumber() {
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 59 + 1);

    if (randomNumbers.includes(number)) {
        return generateUniqNumber();
    }

    return number;
}
addNumsToArray();  
sortArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with `Array#includes()` function .if not then push with array.I was changed with `while` for the iteration count up to 6

```js
var randomNumbers = [];
var number;

function addNumsToArray() {
  var i = 0;
  while (true) {
    number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 59 + 1);
    if (!randomNumbers.includes(number)) {
      randomNumbers.push(number);
    }
    i++;
    if (i== 6) {
      break;
    }
  }
}

function sortArray() {
  randomNumbers.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b
  });
  console.log(randomNumbers);
}

addNumsToArray();
sortArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two approaches to this

first

- generating a random number (from your set)
- checking wether the result already contains this number
- if not, add this number
- repeat untill you have enough numbers

```
function numericAscending(a,b){ return a-b; }

function lotteryNumbers(){
  var numbers = [];
  while(numbers.length < 6){
    var nr = Math.floor(Math.random() * 59 + 1);
    if(!numbers.includes(nr))
      numbers.push(nr);
  }
  return numbers.sort(numericAscending);
}
```

This approach is good if you want a only few numbers out of a big set, since collisions are rare here.

And second, since you have a pretty small set of numbers, you could

- createa an array, containing all possible numbers
- shuffle this Array
- and take as many as you need

```
function shuffle(array){
  for(var i=array.length; i--; ){
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
    if(i === j) continue;
    var tmp = array[j];
    array[j] = array[i];
    array[i] = tmp;
  }
  return array;
}

function lotteryNumbers(){
  var allPossibleLotteryNumbers = [];
  for(var i=1; i<=60;++i)
    allPossibleLotteryNumbers.push(i);

  return shuffle(allPossibleLotteryNumbers).slice(0, 6).sort(numericAscending);
}
```

This approach is recommended when you want a majority of the numbers in the set, since to the end the first approach will create tons of random numbers that are already in the results. Or as here, if your set of numbers is so tiny that you don't have to care about storing all numbers in an Array.

And since your set doesn't change here, you could store the Array of Numbers outside the function

```
var allPossibleLotteryNumbers = [];
for(var i=1; i<=60;++i)
  allPossibleLotteryNumbers.push(i);

function lotteryNumbers(){
  return shuffle(allPossibleLotteryNumbers).slice(0, 6).sort(numericAscending);
}
```